# RabbitMQ asynchronously

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, .net-core, microservices

I want to process RabbitMQ queue in a consumer service. When I try to follow tutorials, i can see that it processes message by message. But what if processing of some message takes longer (e.g. longer DB response)? Then it won't process anything else.

I would like to have it asynchronous. So it can process another messages during waiting time. I tried this piece of code, it works, but it doesn't seem to me that it is correct (not awaited task followed by ContinueWith):

```
private async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancelationToken)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", DispatchConsumersAsync = true };
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "task_queue",
                                durable: true,
                                exclusive: false,
                                autoDelete: false,
                                arguments: null);

        channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 30, global: false);

        Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages.");

        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            // Is it possible to write following part somehow,
            // 1) so that following task can be awaited ?
            // 2) so I doesn't have to use .ContinueWith ?
            #pragma warning disable CS4014 // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(random.Next(100, 5000), cancelationToken);

                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
            }).ContinueWith((prevTask) =>
            {
                if (!prevTask.IsFaulted)
                {
                    channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
                }

            });
            #pragma warning restore CS4014 // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed


        };

        channel.BasicConsume(queue: "task_queue",
                                autoAck: false,
                                consumer: consumer);

        while (!cancelationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100, cancelationToken);
        }
    }

}
```

If I await that Task.Run, then it won't process any other message until that

```
consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
{
...
};
```

is over.

Comment: Instead of the event consumer check out the basic async consumer.

Comment: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/master/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/api/AsyncDefaultBasicConsumer.cs

Comment: I looked at that "basic async consumer", but I don't know how to use it. How to make it call my method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search I have found, that [EasyNetQ](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ) (SubscribeAsync) does exactly what I need. This library makes using Rabbit MQ a lot easier.